# How do I test a private method in a IIFE, maybe by using reflection?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have some IIFEs in my javascript code structured like:

```
function myIIFE() {
    function mtd1() {}
    function mtd2() {}
    function publicmtd1() {}

    return Object.freeze({
        publicmtd1: publicmtd1
    });
}
```

How can I test the private methods in this IIFE?

I know we are not supposed to test private methods and should move them to public methods if we need to test them.

I am just curious if this can be done. In Java, I am able to test private methods by using reflection to make the methods public and then test them. I am wondering if Javascript has something similar to reflection.

Update: Some of you have pointed that my example code is not an IIFE. You are right. I should have said module instead of IIFE.

Comment: `myIIFE` is not IIFE :)

Comment: You could add public methods designed explicitly to test the private functions.

Answer (score 1):

> IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined.

Your example is not a **IIFE**, but anyways, you can't access the functions defined in the `myIIFE` closure, so therefore, in this shape, you can't test them.